# Compile with long argument list (exceed 128 character) in MS-DOS

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, dos, turbo-c

I am maintaining hardware monitor program, which will be executed in 16-bit MS-DOS.
I use dosbox with TurboC(tcc.exe) as build environment

While the dos command line can't accept command exceed 128 characters ([Ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121059/en-us)) ,
but I have a long argument list like this:

```
tcc.exe -ID:\tc\include -LD:\tc\lib -o MyProgram.exe MyProgram.cpp A.obj B.obj C.obj .........
```

So I can't build the code successfully. Anyone has idea to overcome this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe put your `.obj` files into a library and link against that?

Comment: Another option is described on the msdn website. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473

Comment: Consider using the `@` notation. Better yet, switch to Linux & GCC!

Comment: @FredLarson : Like 'ar' in gcc? Does Turbo C has ability to do it ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : @ notation ? How to ? I also want to switch to linux/gcc, but it must communicate with client first.

Comment: @Brightshine: I'm sure it can be done, but I don't remember how. It has been at least 20 years since I used Turbo C.

Comment: @FredLarson: I found tlib can do it! http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/TLIB.EXE,_the_Library_Manager

Answer (score 3):

Check your compiler documentation.  Many compilers allow parameters to be placed into a text file and the name of the text file given as a command line parameter.

For example, if "compiler_options.txt" hold commands than the following may be how to pass the file:

```
tcc.exe @compiler_options.txt
```

Read the documentation to find out if the capability is supported and the correct command line syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the value to it's maximum in the CONFIG.SYS file:
`shell=c:\windows\command.com /u:250 /p`

Comment: Note that `command.com` only supports the `/u:` parameter in Windows 95 and later; `/u:250` produces an `Invalid switch` error in MS-DOS 6.22 (and earlier). Also, in Windows 95, the maximum is `/u:255` not `/u:250`.  Windows 95 accepts `command.com /u:255` but `command.com /u:256` fails with the error message `Parameter value not in allowed range`